# how do display tooltip when move mouse to for each item in editable-select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying display tooltip when move mouse into each item in editable-select.

```
    <a href="#" editable-select="user.status" e-multiple e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">
   click me
  </a>
```

When I click on the link "click me", the editable select preview. I want display  tooltip when I move mouse to each item in editable select. I'm tried search on the internet but could not find I need. So, who can any ideal for my question?  Please help me... thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author want to see that:

[image]

If I understand correctly, the library (that use author) doesn't have directive-option for. So, I write directive with code below (jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fenex/54q4kpmu/)):

```
.directive('eTooltip', function($interval) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var key = attrs.eTooltip;
            var field = attrs.eTooltipField;

            function addTitles() {
                var options = element.next().find('option');
                do {
                     if (scope.$eval(key)) {
                        break;
                    }
                } while(scope = scope.$parent);

                if(!scope)
                    return;

                var myList = scope.$eval(key);
                for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
                    if(!myList[i]) {
                        break;
                    }
                    options[i].setAttribute('title', myList[i][field]);
                }
            }

            function check() {
                var classes = element[0].classList;
                for(var i=0; i<classes.length; i++)
                    if(classes[i] == 'editable-hide')
                        return addTitles();
            }

            $interval(check, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

---

Angular Bootstrap has a tooltips. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip
But it's a large library. Of course, exists other, little library. And you may to write your own module, but it takes time. =)

Comment: tks. I know tooltip in bootstrap. But In there tut can't use for my question... :(

Comment: @PhanSinh. What do you want: write your own tooltip or find existing? One github contains many reps with key words angular+tooltip.

Comment: oh... i'm searched. but could not find i need. So, how to insert a title the tag option?

Comment: With my code just show:<option value="0">status1</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">status2</option>
<option value="2">status3</option>
have not title in tag option to show tile. So how can repair code: <a href="#" editable-select="user.status" e-multiple e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">
   click me
  </a>     to do it? If have title (ex: <option value="1" selected="selected" title="des 1">status2</option>) i can show a title

Comment: ah, i wrong understood you.
if the library doesn't support special option for tooltip, then it makes not easy. You may write special directive, which will listen sibling `form` element, find `option` elements and add `title` attributes.

Comment: this my code: http://embed.plnkr.co/8UKOBgqvpbCSTk3XbHL1/index.html  can you help me to display a message when i move mouse into each item in editable select? pls... tks so much....

Comment: @PhanSinh, I created directive eTooltip for you. [see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fenex/54q4kpmu/). But you need to complete the directive, because it adds title with some text.

Comment: it just show a title when i move mouse to {{ showStatus() }}  and your code can't show status text just display {{showStatus()}}. The editable select will show list: this my image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwqA47J6OrO_YjkxN1FBdG5makk/view
in the image you can see list in the editable select, and i want display a message (ex: title, tooltip,..) when i move mouse to each item (status1 or status 2,...) .

Comment: @PhanSinh my jsfiddle works: http://oi60.tinypic.com/hvs6dw.jpg . I updated the comment, perhaps you went to link before my updating.

Comment: oh tks it's worked. so if $scope.statuses = [
    {value: 1, text: 'status1', titles="des 1"},
    {value: 2, text: 'status2', titles="des 2"},
    {value: 3, text: 'status3', titles="des 3"},
    {value: 4, text: 'status4', titles="des 4"}
  ];
you can help me show title is titles?

Comment: and Please don't use CSS :D

Comment: @PhanSinh, not at all. =)
I updated the answer, don't forget to check the answer as correct, so other people can to find their problem faster.

Comment: tks. so how can create a directive in controller?

Comment: Have any ideal to do it don't use directive?.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of js plugins to do this, but if you want to keep things simple, use the `title` anchor attribute.

Ex.

`<a href="/some/link" title="Click Here">Link</a>`

If you need to bind it to a value, just use the normal angular binding of {}.

Comment: tks for your answer. But i think it can't display a message when i move mouse to the item in editable select. I know use title and tooltip for display a message when move mouse to the link, button, or text, but i don't know how to display a message when i move mouse to the each item in editable select. If use option tag can do display message when move mouse to item but it in option select, not editable select. And i want do it in editable-select. Tks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to find out the name of the template used by the `editable-select` directive (that template will be included in the library and its path can be found in the directive source code). You can then copy the template, add the tooltip-showing capability you want, and replace the original template with your new template in your code using `$templateCache.put()` ([see documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)).

*Edit:* I've looked into the source code myself and unfortunately, it's not as easy as that. Maybe try providing your own `<option>`s in the select then.

Comment: tks.. so have any ideal to do my question?.